# Without table tag create a table with fixed header and first column in cases

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have searched all over internet but I couldn't find any table that is made without table tags with first column and header FIXED. But it's not fixed always, first column is fixed when I move to the right and it's not fixed when I move to down. 
Also header is fixed only in case when I move down, not when I move from left to right.
Those are my requirements.

Could you lead me to some source where I can find more about this table and I have to mention, it needs to be responsive
This is the code that I have so far.

```css
#mapview{
  overflow: scroll;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  height: 216px;
}
#mapview-table {
  min-height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
.mapview-header {
  background-color: #1cc7ff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 35px;
  z-index: 50;
}
.mapview-first-column {
  background-color: #2a6496;
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.mapview-actions{
  min-width: 250px;
  min-height: 250px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="mapview">
    <div id="mapview-table">
        <div class="mapview-header">
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                <?= __('Actions') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapview-first-column">
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-row mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                test column
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-row mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testColumn
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-row mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testColumn
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapview-row">
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
            <div class="mapview-actions mapview-item mapview-item-content">
                testRow
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But this is obviously not good enough. 
[enter link description here](http://zurb.com/playground/playground/responsive-tables/index.html) - I have seen all over internet the solutions, but they are all using table tag.

Comment: Why are you avoiding using a `table`?

Comment: It's alright to use `<table>` for tables.

Comment: Yes, for me it was all right. But my boss told that tables are out of question and I don't want to argue with him. As a matter of fact I agree with you.

Comment: You could consider using display:table etc

Comment: Yezz, I could consider using a lot of stuff. As a matter of fact, I have built the same behavior using the table tags in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use `position: fixed;` to adapt your divs as you want. Here you have an example over your code : https://jsfiddle.net/josegallom/hojL98do/4/

Comment: Jose Gallo, thanks for the response, but when user wants to scroll from left to right, I want the header to move and also when a user wants to scroll from top down then I want first column to move.